# Foundation to Tailwind CSS: central alignment for grid items?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, tailwind-css

How to make the grid items centred align in Tailwind just like we can do that in [Foundation](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/flexbox-utilities.html#central-alignment)?

Foundation:

```
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x align-center-middle text-center" style="height: 200px;">
  <div class="cell small-4">I am in the center-middle</div>
  <div class="cell small-4">I am also centrally located</div>
</div>
```

What about in Tailwind CSS? What else should I use from TW in the code below?

```
  <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
    <div class="bg-green-500">1</div>
    <div class="bg-green-500">2</div>
    <div class="bg-green-500">3</div>
    <div class="bg-green-500">4</div>
    <div class="bg-green-500">5</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Foundation example is using flex, not grid... their flex is just called grid. Recreating the example you shared from Foundation would look something like this Play example in Tailwind. https://play.tailwindcss.com/l6NYNTwPH2 with the flex children having a width of 1/3.

However, from your code example it seems you're looking for 2 rows of 3 columns centered. In Tailwind you will need to wrap each group of 3 in it's own div and if you want them centered horizontally and vertically dropping the width of the flex children to 1/4 would be best since at 1/3 it will go full width. Here's an example of that https://play.tailwindcss.com/kjfzlD2SA7

Surely there are many other solutions to this problem as always with CSS but this one works similar to what you shared from Foundation.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer and explanation.

Comment: You're welcome, hope it helps you find the right layout for your needs.

Comment: it does help. Still trying to get my head around it. Might need to ask another question later! lol

Comment: i like this one,thankyou @JHeth