# Foundation to Tailwind CSS: grid-padding-x and grid-margin-x?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, tailwind-css, gutter

How do we do gutters in Tailwind CSS?

My attempt with [gap-4](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap) below:

```
<div class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-64 bg-green-100 gap-4">

    <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center items-center gap-4 w-full">
      <div class="bg-green-500 w-1/2 text-center">1</div>
      <div class="bg-green-500 w-1/2 text-center">1</div>
      <div class="bg-green-500 w-1/2 text-center">1</div>
      <div class="bg-green-500 w-1/2 text-center">1</div>
      <div class="bg-green-500 w-1/2 text-center">1</div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

But the [result](https://play.tailwindcss.com/YRZtTyH6Ah) is not what I am trying to achieve as the [gutters](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/xy-grid.html#gutters) in Foundation:

```
<div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
  <div class="cell medium-6 large-4">12/6/4 cells</div>
  <div class="cell medium-6 large-8">12/6/8 cells</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
  <div class="cell medium-6 large-4">12/6/4 cells</div>
  <div class="cell medium-6 large-8">12/6/8 cells</div>
</div>
```

Is it [gaps](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap) that I should look for in TW? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Use `space-x-<n>` and/or `space-y-<n>` ([Space Between](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space)) for flexbox.

Use `gap-<n>` ([Gap](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap)) for grids.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="flex flex-row space-x-4 bg-red-200">
  <div class="bg-red-400 p-4 flex-grow">Flex</div>
  <div class="bg-red-400 p-4 flex-grow">Flex</div>
  <div class="bg-red-400 p-4 flex-grow">Flex</div>
  <div class="bg-red-400 p-4 flex-grow">Flex</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="grid grid-flow-row grid-cols-4 gap-4 bg-blue-200">
  <div class="bg-blue-400 p-4">Grid</div>
  <div class="bg-blue-400 p-4">Grid</div>
  <div class="bg-blue-400 p-4">Grid</div>
  <div class="bg-blue-400 p-4">Grid</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I need to have `w-1/2` to make two columns with equal width just as in Foundation...

Comment: @laukok is the grid solution not working for you? You can just adjust the class names like `grid-cols-2` to make it half-width.

Comment: Using grid has an issue that I just raised here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68448637/foundation-to-tailwind-css-central-alignment-for-grid-items